# React- Conditionally applying css in div but it does not work

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, react-css-modules

Have looked at other examples and trying to do the same thing but not sure why my code is not working. I have code which loops through some keys and renders a div. I want to conditionally apply some styles based on whether the key is even or odd. Example:

```
<div className={parseInt(key) % 2 === 0  ? 'label1' : 'label2' }>
     <span style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}>{key}:00</span>
</div>
```

The styles are accessible in the same file and look something like:

```
# Material UI 
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  label1: {
    width: "50px",
    height: "16px",
    top: "458px",
    background: "yellow",
    fontSize: "12px",
  },
  label2: {
    width: "50px",
    height: "16px",
    top: "458px",
    background: "red",
    fontSize: "12px",
  }, 
}));
```

What am I doing wrong? Currently no style is getting applied to the div

Comment: Are the classes being switched in the DOM accordingly ?

Comment: Currently no style is getting applied with the above code. code

Comment: <div className={`parseInt(key) % 2 === 0  ? 'label1' : 'label2' `}>
     <span style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}>{key}:00</span>
</div>
Can you try this once. Add Tilde after { and close Tilde before} in the className

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the classes from the material ui `useStyles` hook.

```
const classes = useStyles()

....

<div className={parseInt(key) % 2 === 0  ? classes.label1 : classes.label2 }>
     <span style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}>{key}:00</span>
</div>
```

Check the `useStyles` hook api: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/

If you have a class component and you can use hooks then you  can do it with the `withStyles` higher order component, like this example:

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"

const styles = theme => ({
  label1: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  label2: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
})

class ClassComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    searchNodes: "",
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props
    return (
      <div className={parseInt(key) % 2 === 0 ? classes.label1 : classes.label2}>
        <span style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}>{key}:00</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(ClassComponent)
```

Comment: What if its not a functional component, instead a class one

Comment: This worked !! It was the ' '  around the classname which was the offender. Thank you for your help! @constantin

Comment: It wasnt just the string,  the classes are added to the object as a property, so you would get the class name by getting the `label1` prop from the object created by `useStyles` or `withStyles`. Glad i could help!

Comment: Yea you are right, forgot to mention I had previously tried something like 'classes.label1' but that had not worked. Removing the ' ' did the trick!